# Where can I learn the meanings of RPG terminology?

Tags: terminology

Words like 'campaign', 'system', 'dX', etc. Is there a good web resource with them all on a single page?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The best way to learn the meanings of RPG terminology is from the introduction to the specific gaming book you're reading at the time**

However, there are some useful glossaries on the web that cover industry-wide terms. Be advised that there are few standards and some games play fast and lose with established practice:

- http://www.theescapist.com/faq_terms.htm Has a brief, but illustrated glossary.
- http://www.boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/RPG_Glossary is a longer glossary.

Comment: thanks. the other answers were great too, but the glossaries here are a perfect balance between specialisation and generalisation.

Comment: @ixtmixilix Fair warning: some info about editions of certain games seems to be outdated. But the general terms look OK.

Answer (score 10):

Here are some good resources I have used.

- Wikipedia - [RPG Game Terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-playing_game_terms)
- RPG Talk wiki - [Terms](http://rpgtalk.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aTerms)
- [RPG Lexica](http://wiki.rpg.net/index.php/RPG_Lexica%3aMain_Page)
  (Probably the best of the three)

Answer (score 5):

The original comprehensive list was the venerable RPG Glossary that was hosted at the now-defunct Treasure Tables blog. Fortunately, it's been archived in the Wayback Machine:

- [RPG Glossary](http://web.archive.org/web/20080601034821/http://www.treasuretables.org/rpg-glossary)

Several other sites have roleplaying glossaries that might eventually usurp the RPG Glossary:

- Gnome Stew's [Gnomenclature: A (Not So) Diminutive Glossary](http://www.gnomestew.com/tools-for-gms/gnomenclature-a-diminutive-rpg-glossary) (note that Gnome Stew was co-founded by the author of Treasure Tables)
- RPGGeek's [RPG Glossary](http://rpggeek.com/wiki/page/RPG_Glossary)
- Darkshire's [A Tabletop RPG Glossary](http://www.darkshire.net/jhkim/rpg/systemdesign/glossary.html)